Cartopy does not format longitude/latitude axis
I try to plot a map with cartopy, and label latitudes with some digits.
See the following code.
The last two lines are not effective, and cartopy still displays latitudes as '7.5°S 7°S ...', when it should be '7.5°S 7.0°S ...'
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cartopy.mpl.ticker, cartopy.crs as ccrs

# Describe the model projection in the file
ProjIn   = ccrs.PlateCarree (central_longitude=0) 
# Projection for plots
ProjPlot = ccrs.PlateCarree (central_longitude=0) 

# Creates the figure
fig, ax = plt.subplots ( figsize=(15,6), subplot_kw={'projection':ProjPlot} )
ax.set_extent ( ( -60, 10, -10, 10,), crs=ProjIn )
ax.gridlines (draw_labels=True, crs=ProjIn)
ax.coastlines ()

# Format axes
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter (cartopy.mpl.ticker.LongitudeFormatter(dms=False, number_format='03.1f'))
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter (cartopy.mpl.ticker.LatitudeFormatter (dms=False, number_format='03.1f'))

Do I miss something ? Is this a bug or a feature ?
Thanks,
Olivier

Seems like you (must?) set the ticks first in order to let the formatting take effect :
ax.set_xticks(np.arange(-60, 10, 10), crs=ccrs.PlateCarree())
ax.set_yticks(np.arange(-10, 10, 2.5), crs=ccrs.PlateCarree())

ax.gridlines(draw_labels=False, crs=ProjIn)

Not sure if it's a bug, but you can definitely specify the x/y formatters in the gridlines: :
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cartopy.mpl.ticker, cartopy.crs as ccrs

proj = ccrs.PlateCarree(central_longitude=0)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15, 6), subplot_kw={"projection": proj})

ax.set_extent((-60, 10, -10, 10), crs=proj)

lon_fmt = cartopy.mpl.ticker.LongitudeFormatter(number_format=".1f")
lat_fmt = cartopy.mpl.ticker.LatitudeFormatter(number_format=".1f")

ax.gridlines(draw_labels=True, crs=proj, xformatter=lon_fmt, yformatter=lat_fmt)

ax.coastlines()


Nice solution, thanks !

Nice solution, thanks :-)
As there is a solution to obtain this plot, I guess that having to use this workaround demonstrates that this is a bug (?)
Olivier

It’s not a bug.  gridlines uses a Cartopy-specific object (the GridLiner) to draw the lines and labels.  This object is separate from Matplotlib’s Axis objects so modifying those cannot affect what the GridLiner draws.
